# Sax Parse exception : unknown type

Tags: xml, aem, sax

We have to include an attribute value as json string in an XML for the application to read. This would look something like

```
<mytag attribute1="{'type':'foo/bar'}">
  .............
</mytag>
```

But while parsing this configuration file, application is throwing a SAX Exception:

```
 org.xml.sax.SAXException: unknown type: 'type':'foo/bar'
```

Any pointers for solving this issue would be helpful

Thanks

Comment: Some sources say you don't need to escape the ' when using " for the attribute, but still it would be worth a try to use &apos; instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too, if you're using a '{' at the **start** of an attribute, you will get a SAXException. I fixed my issue by putting a '\' before it. In your case it would be attribute1="\{'type':'foo/bar'}".